# Samsung Zirconia Protection crash

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have to publish a paid app on Samsung Apps, so I have tried to implement Zirconia license management protection for Android, following [the guide](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/How-to-protect-your-app-from-illegal-copy-using-Samsung-Application-License-Management-Zirconia) on the official Samsung Developer Site.

I have added the Zirconia.jar library to the build path, and the `armeabi` folder with the file `libnativeinterface.so` in the libs folder of the project.

When I try to run this simple test project

```
class MyLicenseCheckListener implements LicenseCheckListener {

    public void licenseCheckedAsValid() {
        Log.d("ZirconiaTest", "License is valid");

        ownerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ownerTextView.setText("Licenza verificata correttamente");
            }
        });
    }

    public void licenseCheckedAsInvalid() {
        Log.d("ZirconiaTest", "License is invalid");

        ownerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ownerTextView.setText("Licenza non valida");
            }
        });
    }

    Handler ownerHandler;
    TextView ownerTextView;
}

public class ZirconiaTest extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText( "This is a simple test application for Zirconia!\nPlease hold on while verifying the license..." );
        setContentView(tv);

        Zirconia zirconia = new Zirconia(this);

        zirconia.doVariablesTest();

        MyLicenseCheckListener listener = new MyLicenseCheckListener();
        listener.ownerHandler = handler;
        listener.ownerTextView = tv;
        //zirconia.setBogusIMEI("");
        zirconia.setLicenseCheckListener(listener);
        zirconia.checkLicense(false, false);

        zirconia.doVariablesTest();        
    }
}
```

I get this error and app crashes

```
01-04 22:09:23.519: E/dalvikvm(28775): Could not find class 'com.samsung.zirconia.Zirconia', referenced from method com.samsung.zirconia.test.ZirconiaTest.onCreate
01-04 22:09:23.519: W/dalvikvm(28775): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9 (Lcom/samsung/zirconia/Zirconia;) in Lcom/samsung/zirconia/test/ZirconiaTest;
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question which I had forgotten.
This problem was caused by a corrupted Eclipse cache, deleting `.metadata` folder and recompiling the project the issue gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i had this error too. Here is solution :

1. Drag "Zirconia.jar" file and drop this into "libs" folder in your project, in Eclipse. Don't delete this from bulid path ! I attached photo for you. I hope I helped

[image: My image]

Comment: The problem is another, Zirconia.jar is already present in lib folder